# VB.Net 2008 IDE hanging - MSVB7.dll eating 100% CPU when editing code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

Edit 1: Uninstalled & Reinstalled
Edit 2: Same problem. Seriously? Yes.

I am having a problem with msvb7.dll eating 50%+ cpu on my dual core system.  This usually lasts 10-30 seconds or so, during which time the IDE is non-responsive.

This occurs when I do pretty much anything in the text editor, and can be replicated by simply adding blank lines to a function, and then deleting them.  Or pasting some code.  Or... lotsa stuff.

- SP1 installed
- I had DevExpress' refactor/coderush, components, and codeit.right installed, but have removed all 3 of them.

  - (I had installed the latest version of Refactor Pro!  (9.3.4), perhaps the day before)
- I have tried a VS.NET Repair.
- There is a kb that referenced some cpu destroying with vb, but it was included in SP1

Also:

- The solution consists of ~30 VB projects and 2 C# projects
- 8 other developers aren't having any issues with this (or at least not the SAME issues, we all have em)
- Clean get from TFS was done
- Project builds properly, can can even debug.
- This doesn't seem to happen on really small solutions, but perhaps it does and it just goes away super quick.

Any clues at all as to what might be causing this, or how to fix it?  I REALLY don't want to lose another day uninstalling and reinstalling and patching and so on =)  If that even fixes it.

***Edit*** *looking at these two hotfixes.  Applied 957912, the first one*

> [KB957912: Updates for Visual Studio 2008 SP1 debugging and breakpoints](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957912)
>
> [KB967631: When you debug in Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1, more breakpoints are generated unexpectedly, or the IDE crashes or becomes unresponsive for about 15 seconds](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967631)

Here is the stack trace (process explorer) that I get from the threads window when the `msvb7.dll` is churning.

```
--- title in process explorer [threads] tab for process --------
cpu:49.28%  cswitch delta: 300 to 3500  startaddress: [msvb7.dll+0x4218c]
    msvb7.dll version: 9.0.30729.1
--- actual stack trace -------
ntkrnlpa.exe!KiUnexpectedInterrupt+0x121
ntkrnlpa.exe!ZwYieldExecution+0x1c56
ntkrnlpa.exe!KiDispatchInterrupt+0x72e
NDIS.sys!NdisFreeToBlockPool+0x15e1
// shortened stack trace.  all of these are from msvb7, 
msvb7.dll+0x46ce7 <- 0x2676a <- 0x2698e <- 0x38031 <- 0x2659f <- 0x26644
msvb7.dll+0x25f29 <- 0x2ac7a <- 0x27522 <- 0x274a0 <- 0x2b5ce <- 0x2b6e4
msvb7.dll+0x67d0a <- 0x68551 <- 0x6817b <- 0x681f0 <- 0x67c38 <- 0x65fa8
msvb7.dll+0x666c6 <- 0x6672c <- 0x6673d <- 0x6677c <- 0x667b4 <- 0x63c77
msvb7.dll+0x63e97 <- 0x42c3a <- 0x42bc1 <- 0x41bd7
kernel32.dll!GetModuleFileNameA+0x1b4
```

This is the list of stuff from "copy info" in help->about, shortened to a resonable length.

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 | Version 9.0.30729.1 SP
Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU Service Pack 1 (KB945140)   KB945140
Microsoft .NET Framework | Version 3.5 SP1
Microsoft Visual Basic 2008      
Microsoft Visual C# 2008   
Microsoft Visual F# for Visual Studio 2008   
Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Team Explorer | Version 9.0.30729.1    
Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Tools for Office   
Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2008  
Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU 
  KB944899, KB945282, KB946040, KB946308, KB946344, KB946581, KB947171
  KB947173, KB947180, KB947540, KB947789, KB948127, KB946260, KB946458, KB948816

Microsoft Recipe Framework Package   8.0        
Process Editor WIT Designer   1.4.0.0
Process Editor for Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server, Version 1.4.0.0    
tangible T4 Editor   9.0
tangible T4 Text Template Editor - T4 Editor    
tangibleprojectsystem   1.0  
Team Foundation Server Power Tools   October 2008   
SQL Prompt 4.0 (disabled)
```

Comment: One day I would like to have a solveable vs.net question :( I suppose it'll be an uninstall, as usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *Process Monitor* (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and trace the activity of Visual Studio when it exhibits this behavior. I have done this many times before with great success.

I am actually monitoring Excel on startup to determine why Excel is having problems with a VSTO Add-in. It turns out Excel is trying to also load a previous version, so I have two add-ins loaded. I figured this out in less that a minute. Without *Process Explorer* I might have been troubleshooting for hours or days.

Comment: It has stopped doing it for the moment, after i reinstalled components and ran your cleaner a few times.  

I like the script you posted at http://missico.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!7178D2C79BA0A7E3!370.entry and I have not modified it at all.  Very handy.  I was too lazy to write this one myself, so thanks!  I hope this stays fixed.

Comment: I cannot tell you how many times that script has worked. I run it at least three times a week. Just today I ran it two times (and rebooted twice).  Usually, you have to run it more often with C#, ASP.NET, and C#/ASP.NET. (ASP.NET Web Site Projects with multiple C# and VB.NET are the worst.)

Answer (score 1):

I've seen something similar happen when you have a circular reference in a specific way in a class.  It's trying to show intellisense and ends up in an infinite loop trying to build the list.  I don't remember the exact circumstances now, though.

Comment: I was wondering if there was something like that.  I haven't a clue how to check for it though... not in something this large.

Answer (score 0):

Given up and wiped VS 2008 & all supporting software.  Reinstalling now.  It is fun to debug, but I had to cancel a meeting this morning because I couldn't get anything going.

If I get a job at MS then I'll look into it further... but this one is just too hard for 
me and my limp debugging skills leftover from years doing .net ;)

**DOH!  Reinstalled and it is still broke!  I may actually have to solve this :(**

@amissico: thanks, i had forgotten about that completely.

The problem is somewhere in the parsing thread, and I can't work out how to pinpoint what it is doing wrong. I see lots of FS activity, but nothing that I can identify as wierd.  It just keeps building temp files (all the same name?) It just looks like it is doing everything everytime, the slow way.  I don't know what it *should* look like, though.

Startup is fine, this is mostly happening when I edit files.  It just starts chewing for intellisense, it appears, but why it takes so long is wierd.

Comment: Have you used Process Monitor yet?

Comment: Clear all your Visual Studio "temporary" files. Check out the "Clear Recent" script at http://missico.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!7178D2C79BA0A7E3!370.entry. <b>Modify it for your own needs.</b> For instance, I dislike Flash, so you may want to remove the call to ClearStupidFlash and the other non-Visual Studio calls. Please review the script and verify the contents of the directories before running the script.

Comment: @amissico - yes,, that was what I was refering to.  I see it doing lots of stuff, but nothing that it doesn't do for other projects that work just fine.  It makes a few huge vbcXX.tmp files in ~/temp, but all my solutions do that too.